# Octave: COM interface to Excel is too slow when writing cells. Any way to speed up?

Tags: excel, windows, com, octave, excel-interop

I am trying to combine EXCEL for lab data managing, and Octave for processing.
It involves calling Excel, reading and writing cells.

But for some reason writing to cells is EXTREMELY slow. It takes hours, while doing the same from VBA, or by reading/writing a file takes milliseconds.

Is there a way to speed it up?
Like writing a full array to a column in one step maybe?
COM is preferable because of accessibility of Excel objects, and editing the spreadsheets natively.

```
pkg load windows;
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
xls = Excel.Workbooks.Open('D:/MISC/noise.xlsx');
disp "opened the book"
data=[];
sheet=xls.Sheets("MYDATA");
for i = 7:8007
  data(i-6)= sheet.Cells(i,6).value2;
endfor
disp "scanned the cells to data"
transfer=fir1(128,0.001);
delay=mean(grpdelay(transfer));
results=fftfilt(transfer,data,128);
results(1:delay)=[];
results(end+1:end+delay)=results(end);
disp "calculated the filtered results"

for i = 1:8001
  sheet.Cells(i+6,7).value=data(i);
    if or(mod(i,10)==0, i == 80001)
      printf("\rwriting cells %i%%   ", floor(100*i/8001))
    endif
endfor
disp "cells are written"

xls.Save
disp "saved"
xls.Close(false);
disp "closed"
Excel.Quit();
disp "Quited"
com_delete(sheet);
com_delete(xls);
com_delete(Excel);
pkg unload windows
disp "unloaded"
```

Comment: @Simon Mourier: You are wrong. It is about COM-interface. pkg load windows particularly loads COM-toolbox. Do not mistaken it with COM-port. And unerase the #tag please.

Comment: More, I suspect that it is really in COM interface itself. Some overhead, and Octave is just an unpriveleged user, requred to wait for resources. So some workaround is needed.

Comment: It's you who are wrong (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/com/topusers). This question is not about "COM" it's is about Excel interop (using COM but this is not a COM issue).

Comment: "EXCEL for lab data managing" That is your mistake. Excel is not a database, don't use it as such. There are many database tools out there that you can use instead.

Comment: I can't find any pages describing how to use Excel from Octave, but [this page in the MATLAB docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-a-matlab-application-as-an-automation-client.html) does. Maybe it works similarly in Octave. The main thing you want to accomplish is not looping to read or write individual cells, but to read and write ranges of cells instead. Each COM call will have some overhead, so using a single call to write a range of cells will be much faster than thousands of calls to write individual cells.

Comment: @SimonMourier: If Excel provides COM interface, and Octave uses COM interface, and they are on both its ends, COM is definitely involved in this problem. Please, avoid sophism in technical discussions!

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Probably you are not familiar with the lab work. Sorry, byt the comment on databases is offtopic. Excel is a main R&D lab tool worldwide for decades; allowing for easy numerical data storing and representation. Octave offers advanced numeric algorithms.
Octave and Matlab, while similar in syntax, have different engines, and tollbox code (for avoiding intellectual property collisions).
I already said myself (read the post!) that passing an array to the column would solve the problem. But it is not reflected in the documentation, how to do that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo>"_Each COM call will have some overhead_". Without question, any higher interface has higher overhead.
However, there is a serious broblem in writing, particularly. If you look into the script, first the values are read. It takes no more than 10 seconds! Then the values are written, And it takes more than a hour! I have multiple guesses, one of which is checking for process access rights by COM engine... maybe. I am not familiar how is it implemented there.

Comment: https://octave.sourceforge.io/windows/package_doc/COM-Interface.html - I see no way to control that or give it unconditional write access.

Comment: I know “the lab work” very well. And I know way too many biologists who use Excel to collect and analyze data. That doesn’t mean it’s the right tool. “Everybody else does it too” is never a good excuse. If you are programming in Octave, you have a great opportunity to use a different system to store your data.

Comment: I think it’s worth trying out the MATLAB syntax for the Excel COM interface, there is a good chance it works in the same way in Octave. Have you tried it before dismissing it?

Comment: I did not dismiss it. But I point out that the types are different. I tried selecting the range and applying the value with Range.Resize.value, and got a range filled with the first value of the array. I am asking, if someone knows how to do it correctly in Octave. Maybe there is a way to manipulate the array type to make it compatible with the input which COM-server is expecting??

Answer (score -1):

Do not know the reason why write calls are many times slower than the read calls. But I found why writing range was giving incorrect results.

The problem was simply in the array format. Octave honours the dimensions when calling excel. So a vector is sent as a line, and it should be transposed to write a column. When there is no next line, the previous line (its first member) is just repeated to the end. Not sure who does that, Octave or Excel.

So, the workaround is working.